# Is it possible to overload <> in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I just came to know that you can overload operators in python using `__add__` or `__sub__` etc.
Even `[]` can be overloaded with `__getitem__`. So it is possibe to overload `<>` like `load_text<"file.txt">`.

Comment: I think not. There seems to be only `[]` and `()` available for overloading.

Comment: What *purpose would it serve* to accomplish this?

Comment: Just plain curiosity @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overload an operator that doesn't exist, and since Python doesn't have a bracketed call operator, you can't overload it.  Sometimes you can do tricks like overloading `<` to return an object that has a `>` overload, but it won't work in this case because `>` is a binary operator, and you have nothing to put on the right side.

Python does have a regular call operator that you can overload with `__call__` to get you `load_text("file.txt")`.